# get array of table columns in LINQ To SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How to get an array of data columns via LINQ To SQL? I'm looking for something like this :

```
DataColumn[] dc = DataContext.Table.Columns;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var dataColumns =
    from member in yourDataContext.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(YourMappedType)).DataMembers
    select new DataColumn {
        ColumnName = member.MappedName,
        DataType = (
            member.Type.IsGenericType && member.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
                ? new NullableConverter(member.Type).UnderlyingType
                : member.Type
        ),
        AllowDBNull = member.CanBeNull
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myDataContext.Mapping.GetTable (typeof (Customer)).RowType.DataMembers
```

Comment: how can I cast it to data column ?

Comment: You could do this: this.Mapping.GetTable (typeof (Customer)).RowType.DataMembers.Select (dm => new DataColumn (dm.Name, dm.Type) { AllowDBNull = dm.CanBeNull })

Comment: I got an exception : **DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.**